# apache poi how to refresh the entire workbook

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

My workbook contains more than 10 sheets, all even sheets are formulated which takes the data from the odd numbered sheet.

I'm writing data only to odd numbered sheet (1 3 5 7.....) at the end, I want to refresh entire workbook automatically so that they all, even numbered (0,2,4,6...) sheets get the data for the next page.

I have tried `HSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells` (workbook)  but its not working.

How to refresh the entire workbook, so that the all formulated cells are evaluated at once?

Comment: Define `but its not working` - errors? warnings? etc

Comment: no errors,warnings. but i'm not getting the expected result.The workbook is not getting refreshed.

Comment: What about if you try to explicitly evaluate one single formula cell - does that get properly updated?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the *.xlsx Format instead and work with this code?

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
```

This just solved a similar problem that I was having.